# chef-solo/chef-client local mode doesn't accept attribute override in a json

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have a cookbook and roles.son and environment.json file available. 
I run them through both chef-solo and chef-client -z (local mode).

Both give the ability to add -j flag to pass the roles.json but doesn't provide any easy way of attribute overriding using environment.json. I am not using a server so not pushing it any where.

Am I missing something ?

I have something like this :

```
cookbooks  environment.json  file.txt  local-mode-cache  nodes  roles.json
```

and I'm running the following

1 : chef-client local mode with client.rb:

```
log_level               :info
log_location            "/var/log/chef/client.log"
node_name       "ip-10-201-38-78"
cookbook_path           "/tmp/cookbooks/"
json_attribs        "/tmp/roles.json"
```

**chef-client -z -c client.rb -j roles.json**

2. **chef-solo -c client.rb -j roles.json**

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Can you copy this down to an answer instead?

Comment: @MarkO'Connor - I need to specify both role and attribute information. Is there a way to specify both the information in one json or pass both in different json somehow ?

Comment: Even with solo, role data goes under `./roles/` and is used exactly the same as with normal chef-client (i.e. add the role to the node's run list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -j is not used to specify the role information, see:

- http://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#options

It can be used to specify node attributes, but would have a different format compared to the roles file.

## Update

I suspect you don't need a role at all.

Here's an example of how to specify both node attributes and the run-list in the JSON file passed to chef client:

```
sudo chef-client -z -j node.json
```

The cookbook dependencies are of course located in a "cookbooks" subdir

```
├── node.json
├── cookbooks
    ├── apt ..
    ├── build-essential ..
    ├── chef_handler ..
    ├── compat_resource ..
    ├── homebrew ..
    ├── java ..
    ├── mingw ..
    ├── seven_zip ..
    └── windows ..
```

### node.json

```
{
  "java": {
    "jdk_version":8,
    "install_flavor":"oracle",
    "oracle": {
      "accept_oracle_download_terms":true
    }
  },
  "run_list":[
    "recipe[apt]",
    "recipe[java]"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Ill take a look and confirm.